# Save file object into local file system: NodeJS EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have an application that should be able to download data from MySQL into the user's local file system.

I'm being able to fetch the header and the file object, but I'm not being able to save it into my directory.

This is the function to downloadPDF file

```
/* Function to download pdf file */
function handlesDownloadPDFfile(req, res, next) {
    pmid = '1';
    userAdminDao.handlesDownloadPDFfile(pmid, function (result) {
        console.log(result);        
       
        var filePath = __dirname;
        console.log(filePath);
        var file = 'test.pdf';
        
        res.end(new Buffer(result.pdf_content), 'binary');

        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
            "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + file
        });
        fs.createReadStream(filePath + file).pipe(res);
    })
}
```

`console.log(result)` does give me the pdf object, however, I am not being able to save it into the filePath.

`UPDATE`

I can now download the file, but I get this error

[image]

I also get this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\routes\test.pdf'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at internal/fs/streams.js:136:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:156:23)
```

Thank You and I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

See the docs for [response.end()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback):

> This method signals to the server that all of the response headers and body have been sent; that server should consider this message complete.

In your code, you should replace the order of res.writeHead() and res.end()

Comment: I'm being able to download the file, however, I get this error ```Failed-network error``` after the file is downloaded. Not sure if its a network issue or something to do with the code

Comment: I also get this error ```Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\routes\test.pdf'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at internal/fs/streams.js:136:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:156:23)```